# Why spring dependency doesn't viewed?

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

I have installed STS, created simple console maven application. After I would like add springframework, but seems that master of adding dependency doesn't find nothing.[image]

Should I fix some settings about Maven?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather search http://search.maven.org and paste the XML by hand.

Think how can your Eclipse client find your dependencies among the HUGE amount of artifacts in the server? m2e downloads an index file (which may not always be available) from the Maven repo. This file is very large and it is much less efficient than using a server-side search engine like http://search.maven.org .